# Какое событие нужно вешать на input c чекбоксом, чтобы отслеживать его изменения?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Какое событие вешать на поле ввода с чекбоксом, чтобы отслеживать его изменения?

Повесил событие 'change':

```
var settingsDisableGroupButton = document.getElementById('disable-group-titles');

function disableGroupTitles(event) {
     console.log('changed');
     var typeGroupTitles = $('.type-titles');
     typeGroupTitles.toggleClass('type-titles_disabled');
}

settingsDisableGroupButton.addEventListener('change', disableGroupTitles);
```

Но оно не срабатывает, когда мы меняем атрибут checked этого объекта из сторонней функции:

```
settingsDisableGroupButton.checked = !settingsDisableGroupButton.checked;
```

в чекбоксе ставится галочка, но код, который должен выполниться при измении состояния, не срабатывает.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Onchange` - это событие произошедшее после изменения состояния элемента пользователем.
В вашем случае должно быть что-то вида:

```
    settingsDisableGroupButton.checked = !settingsDisableGroupButton.checked;
    settingsDisableGroupButton.onchange.apply(settingsDisableGroupButton);
```

Comment: Или можно просто использовать функцию, которую вы вызываете в случае срабатывания события (`disableGroupTitles`)

Comment: решение в комментарии подошло

Answer (score 2):

Нужно вызвать событие из сторонней функции, сделать это можно так:

```
settingsDisableGroupButton.checked = !settingsDisableGroupButton.checked;
$('#disable-group-titles').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Это с jQuery. А вопрос задается по чистому javascript...

Comment: в таком случае прошу прощения, не заметил в вопросе хештега #vanillajs
а вот #jquery там как ни странно присутствует

Comment: Вопрос задается с использованием чистого джаваскрипт...

Comment: спасибо! решение на jquery тоже устроит, у меня ведь все равно смешанный код